# Load an URL inside an iFrame in AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, material-design

I am loading a  url in an angular application inside an iframe. Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div layout="column" flex class="content-wrapper" id="primary-col">
       <md-content layout="column" flex class="md-padding">
              <h2>{{selected.name}}</h2>
              <p>{{selected.content}}</p>
              <div class="cell">
                <iframe ng-src="{{selected.imgurl}}"  >  
              </div>
      </md-content>
</div>
```

**App.Js:**

```
var routerApp =angular.module('DiginRt', ['ngMaterial'])
 routerApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdSidenav', 'muppetService', '$timeout','$log', function($scope, $mdSidenav, muppetService, $timeout, $log) {
  var allMuppets = [];

  $scope.selected = null;
  $scope.muppets = allMuppets;
  $scope.selectMuppet = selectMuppet;
  $scope.toggleSidenav = toggleSidenav;

  loadMuppets();

  //*******************
  // Internal Methods
  //*******************
  function loadMuppets() {
    muppetService.loadAll()
      .then(function(muppets){
        allMuppets = muppets;
        $scope.muppets = [].concat(muppets);
        $scope.selected = $scope.muppets[0];
      })
  }

  function toggleSidenav(name) {
    $mdSidenav(name).toggle();
  }

  function selectMuppet(muppet) {
    $scope.selected = angular.isNumber(muppet) ? $scope.muppets[muppet] : muppet;
    $scope.toggleSidenav('left');
  }
}])

    routerApp.service('muppetService', ['$q', function($q) {
      var muppets = [{
          name: 'Product Report',
          iconurl: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-KGsfSssKoEU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAC4/j_0iL_6y3dE/s96-c-k-no/photo.jpg',
          imgurl: 'https://my.infocaptor.com/dash/mt.php?pa=inflation_50da569f84101',
          content: ' '
      }, {
          name: 'Invoice Report',
          iconurl: 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/-cEjxni3_Jig/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/cMW2NEAUf-k/s88-c-k-no/photo.jpg',
          imgurl: 'https://my.infocaptor.com/dash/mt.php?pa=inflation_50da569f84101',
          content: ''
      } ];

      // Promise-based API
      return {
          loadAll: function() {
              // Simulate async nature of real remote calls
              return $q.when(muppets);
          }
      };
    }]);
```

It rerurns an error saying
**Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{selected.imgurl}}
Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.**

Here is the [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/RfrV7LWlUagNjaYxs6Gy?p=preview)

Comment: try `<iframe ng-src="'{{selected.imgurl}}'"  > </iframe>` should work

Comment: @pankajparkar Previously i had it like that, it dint work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to sanitize URL using `$sce` API, by using that you need to make that URL as trusted by calling method `trustAsResourceUrl`.

**Method**

```
$scope.trustSrc = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl;
```

**HTML**

```
<iframe ng-src="{{trustSrc(selected.imgurl)}}"></iframe>
```

Don't forget to add [`$sce`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) dependency on your controller.

[**Working Plunkr with you code**](http://plnkr.co/edit/YlWzMyMZcwcLXHLsIQcZ?p=preview)

Hope this could help you. Thanks.

Comment: @Sajeetharan  have you checked the modified plunkr?

Comment: yes it works. what i meant was, before you post this answer, i tried the same way

Comment: @ashish_pbh Glad to hear that.. Cheers :)

Comment: Careful with using <iframe ng-src="{{trustSrc(selected.imgurl)}}"></iframe> if you are loading multiple iFrames on one page. Due to angular loading vagaries your function trustSrc might get called a lot more times than you realise causing memory leaks. Instead, I recommend to set a url property on the object itself in your directive or controller when loading the data, and then use that url directly. That way you can be sure your code only fires once per item

Comment: I thought unless `src` of iframe gets change it would not reload iframe.. correct me if I'm wrong.. Thanks for heads up though ;) :)

Comment: No worries. Whether it was reloading the whole iFrame I couldn't be sure, but it was certainly calling my function that generated the src link multiple times per iFrame

Comment: @AdamDiment yes, that's how angular call each binding expression over each digest cycle, but AFAIK it wouldn't matter to Iframe unless its `src` gets changed

Comment: If you are sure that the `selected.imgurl` doesn't change, you could one-time bind it using `::`. This would make sure that the `src` doesn't change. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression